# How to Convert integer to char array

Tags: c++

```
int x = 1231212;
memcpy(pDVal, &x, 4);
int iDSize = sizeof(double);
int i = 0;
for (; i<iDSize; i++)
{
    char c;
    memcpy(&c, &(pDVal[i]), 1);
    printf("%d|\n", c);
    printf("%x|\n", c);

}
```

I used above code segment to print the hex value of each byte of a Integer. But that is not working properly. What is issue here ?

Comment: How is `pDVal` declared?

Comment: The code is not clear. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you need sprintf?

Comment: this is tagged C++, do it the C++ way: `std::cout << std::hex << x << std::endl;` that will print the hex value of `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
void Int32ToUInt8Arr( int32 val, uint8 *pBytes )
{
  pBytes[0] = (uint8)val;
  pBytes[1] = (uint8)(val >> 8);
  pBytes[2] = (uint8)(val >> 16);
  pBytes[3] = (uint8)(val >> 24);
}
```

or perhaps:

```
UInt32 arg = 18;
array<Byte>^byteArray = BitConverter::GetBytes( arg);
// {0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }

byteArray->Reverse(byteArray);
// { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x12 }
```

for the second example see: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4(VS.80).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question didnt mention C++/CLI anywhere.

Comment: yes, it's tagged as C++, not "C++/CLI". These are two different languages.

Comment: Uhm, this is wrong. No idea why it was accepted but is doesn't do what the question asks (not even remotely) as you don't actually print anything *and* don't use standardised C++ (as others have noted). Note that `'0' != 0`. No matter what `Byte` is, if you print this straight forward it will produce the wrong outcome, as `31` wont be printed as `1F` but as `31`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) function. You will get a char*, so you have your array.
See the example on the webpage

Comment: `itoa` is a non-standard function. Consider using `sprintf` instead.

Comment: I'm kinda tempted of downvoting this since he tagged it as c++ and you are providing a c answer. But maybe the OP does not know what he wants since his code is also c...

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks awful. That's it.

`memcpy(pDVal, &x, 4);`

What is `pDVal`? Why do you use 4? Is it `sizeof(int)`?

`int iDSize = sizeof(double);`

Why `sizeof(double)`? May be you need `sizeof(int)`.

`memcpy(&c, &(pDVal[i]), 1);` makes copy first byte of i-th array pDVal element.

`printf("%d|\n", c);` is not working because "%d" is waiting integer.

Comment: I agree with the rest of the comments, but the last is not a problem.  Passing a `char` as a vararg will result in integral promotion taking place, and the `char` will be converted to `int` (possibly not with the value he expects---on a lot of machines, `char` is signed).

Comment: `"%d" is waiting integer` ?? So, he's passing a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Print like this:

```
printf("%d|\n", c & 0xff);
printf("%x|\n", c & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious about the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), this is how I would suggest to do it.

```
#include <sstream>

template <typename Int>
std::string intToStr(Int const i) {
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << std::hex << i;
  return stream.str();
}
```

Which you may invoke as `intToStr(1231212)`. If you insist on getting a `char` array (I strongly suggest you use `std::string`), you can copy the `c_str()` result over:

```
std::string const str = intToStr(1231212);
char* const chrs = new char[str.length()+1];
strcpy(chrs,str.c_str()); // needs <string.h>
```